# What does ''formal" mean in "formal park" phrase?

Tags: meaning

What does ''formal" mean in "formal park" phrase? Here is an excerpt:

> Now to the Bicentennial Park itself. It has two areas, a nature reserve and a formal park with man-made features and gardens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It talks about two distinct areas. One which is natural and the other that is manmade i.e. developed according to the plan.

OALD has this definition.

> [formal](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/formal) - *(of a garden, room or building) arranged in a regular manner, according to a clear, exact plan*

Answer (score 2):

*Formal park* is similar in meaning to *formal garden*, which suggests an elaborate, precise, and carefully designed layout.

A Google Images search for "garden" and "formal garden" should give you an idea.